# Elasticsearch, how to get all unique values of a field and count of total unique values?

Tags: java, elasticsearch, aggregation, facet

In Elasticsearch, We have used terms facet and terms aggregations to cope with the above mentioned problem. Unfortunately, this will surely work for small set of data. But we are dealing with data which would be around 10 million documents.

Hence, when we query to fetch all the unique values for field(Eg. company field) by using aggregation(setting "size":0) or facet(using "exclude"), we would not be able to get entire result in one stretch. It seems that elasticsearch would take lot of time to respond and ultimately it results in node failure.

The sole purpose of this process was to get count of how many unique values are present in a field(Eg. company, count of unique companies).

Any suggestions would be appreciable.

Comment: can you provide your current mapping and your query, which you use to retrieve the facets?

Comment: "company" :{"type":"string","fields":{"company_raw":{"type":"string","analyzer":"lowercaseAnalyzer"}}}. We are querying on company_raw field since it is a "not-analyzed" field.

Comment: Is it realy not-analyzed? is the lowercaseAnalyzer without tokenization?

Comment: ya it is not-analyzed. it is an analyzer name which also containes tokenization field. we have set that to "keyword".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use Elasticsearch 1.1.0 or above, you can try to **estimate** the distinct counts with [cardinal aggregations](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-cardinality-aggregation.html).

A simple query would look like this in your case:

```
POST /{yourIndex}/{yourType}/_search
{
    "aggs" : {
        "company_count" : {
            "cardinality" : {
                "field" : "company.company_raw",
                "precision_threshold": 10000
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is really helpful. But there is deviations in the total count for different "precision_threshold" values. Is there a way to solve this? i.e, to get constant value for different "precision_threshold" values.

Comment: No, `precision_threshold` defines a unique count below which counts are expected to be close to accurate, so if you use the max of `40.000`, it is the best possible estimation you can get. If you vary this value, the estimation will also change and can not be constant.

Comment: Does it mean that if I have more than 40,000 unique values, I will always get an estimate?